# How to detect ListView is scrolling up or down

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, winrt-xaml-toolkit

Is there a way to detect that `ScrollViwer` of `ListView` is in scrolling mode and stopped scrolling. In windows phone 8.1 `ListView` we can not get reference of the scrollviewer.

Any one done it in windows phone 8.1 WinRT app?

Comment: As I think, you should accept @yasen answer - he was faster (3 seconds) and after edit has much better method of traversing the *VisualTree* ;)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. I have changed the accepted answer thanks again :)

Comment: @Romasz Thanks. Your answer is good too, as always. :) Only a bit less generic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once the ListView is `Loaded` you can get the `ScrollViewer` like this:

```cs
var sv = (ScrollViewer)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this.ListV, 0), 0);
```

**Edit**

As Romasz suggested, once you get the `ScrollViewer`, you can use its `ViewChanged` event, to monitor when it is scrolling and when it stops.

Also, here's the generic extension method that I use for traversing the visual tree:

```cs
// The method traverses the visual tree lazily, layer by layer
// and returns the objects of the desired type
public static IEnumerable<T> GetChildrenOfType<T>(this DependencyObject start) where T : class 
{
    var queue = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
    queue.Enqueue(start);

    while (queue.Count > 0) {
        var item = queue.Dequeue();

        var realItem = item as T;
        if (realItem != null) {
             yield return realItem;
        }

        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(item);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            queue.Enqueue(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(item, i));
        }
    }
}
```

To get the `ScrollViewer` using this methos, do this:

```cs
var sv = yourListView.GetChildrenOfType<ScrollViewer>().First();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can find the *ScrollViewer* of your *ListView* by using *VisualTreeHelper*. For example like this:

```cs
// method to pull out a ScrollViewer
public static ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject depObj)
{
    if (depObj is ScrollViewer) return depObj as ScrollViewer;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

        var result = GetScrollViewer(child);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Once you have a *ScrollViewer* you can subscribe to its events:

```cs
GetScrollViewer(yourListView).ViewChanged += yourEvent_ViewChanged;
```

Comment: I am using IsupportIncrementalLoading extended class for populating the list view, where the items are loaded from internet. How can I get the scrollviewer in this case, since the listview take some time to populate the child items.

Comment: @MohanRajNK And where is the problem - what are you trying to achieve? As I think ListView has one scrollviewer and incremental loading just loads items when needed.

Comment: The problem is how can I get a scrollviewer? I called the getscrollviewer method inside the listview loaded method. But at that time the listview has no child items. i.e GetChildrenCount returns 0.

Comment: @MohanRajNK I've not played with that much. In this case I think it will be more suitable just to ask new question on SO.

Comment: Worked. Thanks. I should research more before I ask a question. Sorry!

Comment: @MohanRajNK I'm not sure why you have deleted the question - it was a good one - may help somebody in future.