# Detect end of ListView Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

i have seen a way to detect end of listview for Windows 8 app and i was wandering how to achieve this in 8.1 (being precise - for windows phone 8.1).

I tried [this method](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-xaml-automatically-scrolling-listview-to-bottom-and-detecting-when-listview-is-scrolled/) but this works with windows 8 - i dunno how to get scrollview from listview in 8.1 (or is it even possible?).

Is there any other way?

Comment: You can [retrive the scrollviewer from Listview](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27294439/2681948).

Comment: So different question - I have ViewChanged and ViewChanging events but if i am already at the end of list and when i try to go further down neither of the events fires. How i can start them - or should i just detect end and then do what i want to?

Comment: If you are at the end of the list and you try to move further? Then as I think the list will remain in the same position - view won't change - maybe consider other events - tapped or other.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you want to do when the user scrolls after the last item?

Comment: I want to download older data when the user goest to the bottom of the list - i got it working with ScrollViewChanged :)

Comment: You should implement [ISupportIncrementalLoading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh701916) instead (despite how broken it is). Check out the [XAML data binding sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Data-Binding-7b1d67b5) for a working example of how to do this.