# How to get text from TextBox inside ListViewItem's DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I don't know how to get text from "firstBox" and "secondBox" after button click.

```xml
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
       <!-- some code -->
       <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Data}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="18" Width="100" FontSize="13.333" Margin="162,9,0,0"/>
       <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,35,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding D_gospodarzy}" FontSize="14.667" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="59" Width="100"/>
       <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="268,35,7,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding D_gosci}" FontSize="14.667" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="59"/>
       <TextBox x:Name="firstBox" ... />
       <Button Content="Click" " Click="Button_Click_1"/>
       <TextBox x:Name="secondBox" ... />
     </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I get only the object

```cs
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var myobject = (sender as Button).DataContext;            
}
```

Comment: See this question and the answer from Jerry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375375/how-do-i-access-a-control-inside-a-xaml-datatemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are cuple of ways to do it, for example you can traverse the *VisualTree* of clicked button's parent and retrive *TextBox* with the name you want. In this case, I would take advantage of an extension method written by [yasen in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27294643/2681948).

Then it can look for example like this:

```cs
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var parent = (sender as Button).Parent;
    TextBox firstOne = parent.GetChildrenOfType<TextBox>().First(x => x.Name == "firstBox");
    Debug.WriteLine(firstOne.Text);
}
```

Remember to put an extension method somewhere in a *static* class:

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetChildrenOfType<T>(this DependencyObject start) where T : class
    {
          // rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get the text..

```
 String text1 = firstBox.Text;
 String text2 = secondBox.Text;
```

*note:* `firstBox` and `secondBox` must be class members to use them in different class methods.